# yii relational complex active record task

Tags: php, mysql, activerecord, yii, relational-database

I'm trying to get used to relational active record but things look too complicated for now.
If it's not difficult please point me in right direction.

I have 4 tables.

**Users**

```
userID[pk],userName
```

**Cars**

```
car_id[pk],userID[fk to Users],car_nickname,make_id[fk to Makes],model_id[fk to Models]
```

**Makes**

```
make_id[pk],make_name
```

**Models**

```
model_id[pk],model_name,make_id[fk to Makes]
```

Now input data is `userName,make_name,model_name` and task is to get **car_nickname** from **Cars** table.

Is this possible using relations or should I do it step by step checking makes,models,users for IDs and then puting all IDs into Cars to get car_nickname ?

Answer (score 1):

You can yous only one Model with reliations to all tables. And create one _form.php in the Views, where there will only fields you need.
Some halpfull information. if you save some data into some table and you need saved data `id`, you caN use `$newid = $model->getPrimaryKey();` and assign to new variable , wich will save into other tables. 
I think this is short way to solve problem